# Clojure question mark arrow macro

Tags: clojure, macros

I came across a `?>` statement within a `->` block in some code I was trying to understand. I searched clojuredocs, but came up blank. What does this do?

Code I was trying to understand:

```
(-> (apply time/t -2 date-fields)
             (?> (:grain token-fields) (assoc :grain (:grain token-fields)))
             (?> (:timezone token-fields) (assoc :timezone (:timezone token-fields))))
```

Comment: This is not part of core, so we may need more context. By the looks of it I'd say it's some conditional threading macro perhaps.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found it. It comes from the [Plumbing](https://github.com/plumatic/plumbing) library.

To quote [the docs](http://plumatic.github.io/plumbing/plumbing.core.html#var-.3F.3E):

```
?> macro
(?> arg do-it? & rest)
Conditional single-arrow operation (-> m (?> add-kv? (assoc :k :v)))
```

Here's the actual source code of the macro:

```
(defmacro ?>
  "Conditional single-arrow operation (-> m (?> add-kv? (assoc :k :v)))"
  [arg do-it? & rest]
  `(if ~do-it?
     (-> ~arg ~@rest)
     ~arg))
```